# Saving and retrieving spinner value with sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-sharedpreferences

I have a spinner. I want to save its value in `saveFile()` and retrieve the same on calling `readFile()` using sharedpreferences. I haven't got the right way to do it yet.

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.countries_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    public void saveFile(){
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
     }
    public void readFile(){
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
     public void saveFile(){
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("spinnerValue",spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
            editor.apply();
     }

     public void readFile(){
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int index = sharedPref.getInt("spinnerValue",0);
            spinner.setSelection(index);
     }
```

Comment: Sorry, the app gets closed on starting the activity which contains spinner.

Comment: check you logchat or run tab. what is the exception?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setSelection(int)' on a null object reference. This is it, any solution??

Comment: As it this error clearly points out your spinner is null. either 1) you are calling readfile() before findview the spinner or 2)there is no R.id.spinner in your activity layout

Comment: Now, I call readFile() after findview. What happens now is app gets closed on opening the activity containing spinner for the second time.

Comment: I got it!! I had to call the readFile() after the setAdapter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
  editor.apply();
```

after set preference value.

Comment: I am stuck with the code to save spinner. Could you please help me with the code?

Comment: @BIBINJOHNY implements setOnItemSelectedListener callback and do your logic in it.   Lots of samples about this.

Comment: Please look into @DNA.h 's answer. Is that true? If so, why my app gets closed when I open the activity containing the spinner?

Comment: @BIBINJOHNY check layout xml file to ensure it has a spinner and the id is "spinner"

Comment: I checked, it is the same. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To save data in Shared Preference you have to write data to Shared Preference. For writing data use :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

And to read again use this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default_key);
int highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), defaultValue);
```

Check [official](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) doc for more.